# iPhone 4 (jailbroken with Pangu) giving "no sim card installed" popup that I can't exit

Tags: iphone, crash, jailbreak

I recently jailbroke my iP4 GSM with Pangu and installed Cydia, along with a number of tweaks. However, today, when I opened Opera Mini on my phone, a popup saying "No SIM Card Installed" showed up, and the "OK" button appeared to be unclickable. I tapped on it numerous times, and it wouldn't go away until about a solid minute later. I thought I was okay, so I went back to Springboard and found that all the icons were shifted down, as if I was using spotlight search or had that weird GarageBand red bar on the screen. Neither were present, or even visible. I thought this was weird and started scrolling my pages, when, you guessed it... "No SIM Card Installed." I couldn't even lock the screen while it was doing this, and no restart or respring could help me. I decided to read the logs with Cydia Impactor, and found that they were scrolling faster than I could comprehend:

```
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone locationd[46] <Error>: ATCS dispatcher resetting
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.614916]: Callback reason=DyamicStoreChange
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.619418]: Discovered 2 airport Interfaces
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.620076]: Now attempting to add AirPort Interface with BSDName ap1
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.623264]: No Matching Service Found for interface ap1
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.CommCenter[20039]) <Warning>: (com.apple.CommCenter) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.690333]: Callback reason=DyamicStoreChange
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.701348]: Discovered 2 airport Interfaces
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.703566]: Now attempting to add AirPort Interface with BSDName ap1
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.710205]: No Matching Service Found for interface ap1
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.724020]: Callback reason=DyamicStoreChange
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.728094]: Discovered 2 airport Interfaces
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.729445]: Now attempting to add AirPort Interface with BSDName ap1
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.735586]: No Matching Service Found for interface ap1
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.750033]: Callback reason=DyamicStoreChange
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.753867]: Discovered 2 airport Interfaces
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.755205]: Now attempting to add AirPort Interface with BSDName ap1
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331317.759107]: No Matching Service Found for interface ap1
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone CommCenterClassic[20048] <Error>: objc[20048]: Class CTAsciiAddress is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony and /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenterClassic. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSerialMultiplexer: !! mux-ad(nr)::validateAndGetMuxBsdInterface: Invalid minor 7 for operation Select
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSerialMultiplexer: !! mux-ad(nr)::validateAndGetMuxBsdInterface: Invalid minor 7 for operation Select
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSerialMultiplexer: !! mux-ad(nr)::bsdClose: attempt to close a nonexistent channel 7, ignoring
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone CommCenterClassic[20048] <Error>: objc[20048]: Class CTPhoneNumber is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony and /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenterClassic. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone CommCenterClassic[20047] <Error>: objc[20047]: Class CTAsciiAddress is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony and /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenterClassic. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone CommCenterClassic[20047] <Error>: objc[20047]: Class CTPhoneNumber is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony and /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenterClassic. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 23 06:41:57 Sams-iPhone CommCenterClassic[20047] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Injecting: (null) [CommCenterClassic] (847.27)
Apr 23 06:41:58 Sams-iPhone profiled[20043] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/libstatusbar.dylib
Apr 23 06:41:58 Sams-iPhone CommCenterRootHelper[20049] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Injecting: (null) [CommCenterRootHelper] (847.27)
Apr 23 06:41:58 Sams-iPhone profiled[20043] <Notice>: CoreFoundation = 847.270000
Apr 23 06:41:58 Sams-iPhone profiled[20043] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service starting...
Apr 23 06:41:58 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20047] <Notice>: com.apple.CommCenter.RadioNotReady - Declared system activity to prevent sleep
Apr 23 06:41:58 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20047] <Notice>: Creating with path /dev/dlci.spi-baseband.extra_0
Apr 23 06:41:58 Sams-iPhone CommCenterClassic[20047] <Warning>: opening backingstore /var/wireless/Library/Databases/DataUsage.sqlite, read/write
Apr 23 06:41:58 Sams-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSerialMultiplexer: mux-ad(nr)::timeGetAdjustmentGated: Forcing time update
Apr 23 06:41:58 Sams-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSerialMultiplexer: mux-ad(byp)::dormancySetIntervalGated: Setting dormancy interval to 2500 ms with mask 0x1700
Apr 23 06:41:59 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20047] <Notice>: no MMS settings found, checking for legacy settings
Apr 23 06:41:59 Sams-iPhone CommCenterMobileHelper[20035] <Error>: VM_ALLOCATE 182l (mhs1)
Apr 23 06:41:59 Sams-iPhone locationd[46] <Error>: opening /dev/dlci.spi-baseband.cl1 - 2 No such file or directory
Apr 23 06:41:59 Sams-iPhone locationd[46] <Error>: **** baseband crash collect CSI logs, file a Radar* ****
Apr 23 06:41:59 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20047] <Notice>: Communications Center Started.
Apr 23 06:42:00 Sams-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSerialMultiplexer: mux-ad(byp)::dormancySetIntervalGated: Setting dormancy interval to 2500 ms with mask 0x1700
Apr 23 06:42:00 Sams-iPhone CLTM[20] <Notice>: CLTM: deregistering for wake notification before re-registering
Apr 23 06:42:00 Sams-iPhone CLTM[20] <Notice>: CLTM: deregistered for wake notification
Apr 23 06:42:00 Sams-iPhone CLTM[20] <Notice>: CLTM: registered for wake notification
Apr 23 06:42:00 Sams-iPhone CLTM[20] <Notice>: CLTM: set allowable transmit power limit to 24.000 dBm
Apr 23 06:42:00 Sams-iPhone CLTM[20] <Notice>: CLTM: Set AppleARMPerformanceControllerDVDFactor0 dithering level to 100%
Apr 23 06:42:00 Sams-iPhone CLTM[20] <Notice>: CLTM: setting thermal status level to 0 (0) [2887, 5151, 3193, 3221, 3161, 3180, 3388, 3632, 3643, -32768, 0, 3137, 3016, 3199, 3018, 3242, 3031, 2880, 2695, 2808]
Apr 23 06:42:00 Sams-iPhone SpringBoard[30] <Warning>: background CTServerConnection returned error: (2, 5) in ___updateLocale_block_invoke1012
Apr 23 06:42:00 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20047] <Error>: Failed to load the file
Apr 23 06:42:00 Sams-iPhone ReportCrash[20045] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 20047
Apr 23 06:42:00 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331320.913656]:
Apr 23 06:42:00 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: Too frequent(3.938482 secs) rssi event from driver
Apr 23 06:42:00 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>:
Apr 23 06:42:01 Sams-iPhone ReportCrash[20045] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process CommCenterClassic[20047]
Apr 23 06:42:01 Sams-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.CommCenter[20047]) <Warning>: (com.apple.CommCenter) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Apr 23 06:42:01 Sams-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.CommCenter) <Notice>: (com.apple.CommCenter) Throttling respawn: Will start in 7 seconds
```

There was also a lot of "Comm Center is dead...":

```
Apr 23 06:45:20 Sams-iPhone locationd[46] <Error>: opening /dev/dlci.spi-baseband.cl1 - 2 No such file or directory
Apr 23 06:45:20 Sams-iPhone locationd[46] <Error>: **** baseband crash collect CSI logs, file a Radar* ****
Apr 23 06:45:21 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: WiFi:[609331521.185583]:
Apr 23 06:45:21 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>: Too frequent(3.296632 secs) rssi event from driver
Apr 23 06:45:21 Sams-iPhone wifid[76] <Notice>:
Apr 23 06:45:21 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:21 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:21 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone aggregated[31] <Warning>: Lost connection to CT
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone CommCenter[20147] <Notice>: Carrier bundle does not have PhoneNumberRegistrationGatewayAddress, returning NULL
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone identityservicesd[44] <Warning>: [Warning] Comm center is dead...
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone locationd[46] <Error>: opening /dev/dlci.spi-baseband.cl1 - 2 No such file or directory
Apr 23 06:45:22 Sams-iPhone locationd[46] <Error>: **** baseband crash collect CSI logs, file a Radar* ****
```

No idea what to do. The nice thing is that I have a copy of iOS 6.1.3 that I've dualbooted on the device, so I can still use the thing, at least. Anyone have an answer?

EDIT: GOD HELP ME I CAN'T EVEN REBOOT TO iOS 6 BECAUSE OF THIS

Update: Though it does break a few things, disabling com.apple.CommCenterClassic entirely using launchctl does fix the problem. I tried installing the "SIM Alert Suppresion" tweak, but despite the lack of SIM messages, the phone still kept freezing periodically. Right now, I'm forced to deal with "Searching..." in the status bar and an empty notification dot on the Phone app because I disabled CommCenterClassic. I even tried restoring and rejailbreaking the phone (using Pangu 1.0), but this issue cropped up AGAIN a few days later. This time, unlike previously, my Messages app still had its message history (it was deleted the last time), and I could open FaceTime, which would just freeze and crash the last time this happened. I'm EXTREMELY confused.

Comment: You may have better luck getting an answer for your question at [/r/LegacyJailbreak](https://www.reddit.com/r/LegacyJailbreak/)

Comment: I would rather not go to Reddit to get this solved, as much as I know they can help me. I added a bit more info to the question, maybe someone can help? If not, I'll have to set a bounty or something...